bufferevent unexpected segfault - libevent
I recently started to use libevent in my C networking application and I'm facing an issue with the bufferevents.
I'm using libevent-2.1.12-stable
Code 1:
int tcp_client_send(hv_client_t *cli, char *buf, unsigned int len) {

    if (!cli || !cli->bev || !buf || len <= 0) {
        LERR("Invalid parameters!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(!cli->connected) {
        LERR("Not connected!\n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&cli->lock_) != 0) {
        LERR("Failed to acquire lock!\n");
        return -3;
    }

 // Get the output buffer associated with the bufferevent
    struct evbuffer *ev_buffer = bufferevent_get_output(cli->bev);
    if (!ev_buffer) {
        LERR("Failed to get output buffer!\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
        return -4;
    }

    // Add data to the evbuffer
    if (evbuffer_add(ev_buffer, buf, len) != 0) {
        LERR("Failed to add data to ev_buffer!\n");
        evbuffer_free(ev_buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
        return -5;
    }

    // Flush the output buffer to the socket
    if (bufferevent_flush(cli->bev, EV_WRITE, BEV_FLUSH) != 0) {
        LERR("Failed to flush output buffer!\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
        return -6;
    }

    if (cli->ssl_type == 1) {
        LDEBUG("TLS connection is sending %d bytes data... ", len);
    } else {
        LDEBUG("TCP connection is sending %d bytes data... ", len);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);

    return 0;
}

This code ALWAYS segfaulted after a while with different errors. For example:

#0  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:497
#1  0x00007f7d326255dc in evbuffer_add () from /usr/local/my_app/lib/my_app/modules/transport.so

or

#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007f1def571537 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f1def5c93e8 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f1def6e7390 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007f1def5d06da in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7f1def6e5045 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5347
#4  0x00007f1def5d1894 in _int_free (av=, p=, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4173
#5  0x00007f1def5111fe in evbuffer_chain_insert () from /usr/local/my_app/lib/my_app/modules/transport.so
#6  0x00007f1def51141d in evbuffer_add () from /usr/local/my_app/lib/my_app/modules/transport.so

NOTE 1:
I have already tried using bufferevent_write instead of bufferevent_flush, with the same result.
Code 2:
int tcp_client_send(hv_client_t *cli, const void *buf, int len)
{
    if (!cli || !cli->bev || !buf || len <= 0) {
        LERR("Invalid parameters!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(!cli->connected) {
        LERR("Not connected!\n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&cli->lock_) != 0) {
        LERR("Failed to acquire lock!\n");
        return -3;
    }

    // Create an evbuffer object
    struct evbuffer *ev_buffer = evbuffer_new();
    if (ev_buffer == NULL) {
        LERR("Failed to create evbuffer!\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
        return -4;
    }

    // Add data to the evbuffer
    if (evbuffer_add(ev_buffer, buf, len) != 0) {
        LERR("Failed to add data to ev_buffer!\n");
        evbuffer_free(ev_buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
        return -5;
    }

    // Get the data from the evbuffer
    size_t buffer_len = evbuffer_get_length(ev_buffer);
    if(buffer_len <= 0) {
        LERR("Buffer length cannot be <= 0!\n");
        return -6;
        evbuffer_free(ev_buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
    }
    char *output_data = (char *)calloc(buffer_len, sizeof(char));
    if (output_data == NULL) {
        LERR("Memory allocation failed!\n");
        evbuffer_free(ev_buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
        return -7;
    }
    evbuffer_remove(ev_buffer, output_data, buffer_len);

    // Send the data over the socket
    int nwr = send(bufferevent_getfd(cli->bev), output_data, buffer_len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    if (nwr == -1) {
        // Error handling
        int err = EVUTIL_SOCKET_ERROR();
        fprintf(stderr, "TCP Error sending data: %s\n", evutil_socket_error_to_string(err));
        free(output_data);
        evbuffer_free(ev_buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);
        return -8;

    } else {
        LDEBUG("TCP connection is sending %d bytes data... ", nwr);
    }

    // Free resources
    free(output_data);
    evbuffer_free(ev_buffer);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli->lock_);

    return 0;
}

This code works perfectly, but using send I'm losing the bufferevents functionalities.
I initialized all the bufferevents data structures as expected, I followed the main guide and saw various examples, so the problem is when bufferevent_write or bufferevent_flush is called, apparently on the evbuffer_add called under the hood.
NOTE 2: For now I'm using only one thread but the application is multithreaded
I could not find a clear solution for Code 1.
Any idea ?

OT: return -6; evbuffer_free(ev_buffer); ... -> you never call evbuffer_free(ev_buffer);, also if(buffer_len <= 0) { should be if(buffer_len == 0) { -> size_t is always positive.

Where in your program does the crash happen? You have built with debug information so you can locate it in a debugger? If your compiler have sanitizers, have you tried to enable them to help you catch any possible problems? And if you enable more warnings, does it still build without any warnings?

Also, did the code work before your latest changes? What were those changes that suddenly made the program crash? Perhaps it's possible to create a [mre] to test and debug only the changes you made?

@Someprogrammerdude the crash happens in function if (evbuffer_add(ev_buffer, buf, len) != 0). What kind of warning can I enable? I can also try to check with Valgrind.

Assuming you use either GCC or Clang, build with at least -Wall -Wextra. I also recommend -Werror to turn all warnings into errors. And personally I also use -Wpedantic, and maybe a few others I can't recall right now.

@Someprogrammerdude the original code was the Code 1, then I changed it to Code 2 to make it work. But it never worked for a high traffic rate. The crash happens only after the program ingests quite an amount of data.
I can work to write a minimal reproducible example, sure.

#3 0x00007f1def5d06da in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7f1def6e5045 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5347?  Yep, check with Valgrind.  IME it's likely a double free.

@AndrewHenle yes, for sure it's a double free, but comes directly from the libevent library, as I just called the functions as in various examples and then the free is called internally from a memory region that is not supposed to be freed by libevent, because I do not explicitly alloc or free anything here.
